# Django: DisallowedHost in the new version of Django

Tags: python, django

Up until now I was using Django==1.9.6 in my Vagrant machine inside a virtualenv. However I made a new virtual environment to test out the new Django and installed the latest version of Django (version 1.10.4). And I didn't do anything, but just ran the server

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

When I tried to open the url, instead of `Welcome to Django`, I got an error:

> DisallowedHost at /
>
> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 55.55.55.5

I have however corrected this by setting the IP of my vagrant machine (55.55.55.5) into the ALLOWED_HOST list.

Was this implemented in the newer version of Django, or was this feature already in previous versions of Django but the error occured because of some bad configuration in my settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the (excellent) [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts):

> Changed in Django **1.10.3**:
>
> In older versions, ALLOWED_HOSTS wasn’t checked if DEBUG=True. This was also changed in Django **1.9.11** and **1.8.16** to prevent a DNS rebinding attack.

(emphasis mine)

Also see the release notes for [1.9.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.9.11/#dns-rebinding-vulnerability-when-debug-true) (as noted by @Sayse) for the rationale for this change:

> While Django doesn’t ship a module that allows remote code execution, this is at least a cross-site scripting vector, which could be quite serious if developers load a copy of the production database in development or connect to some production services for which there’s no development instance, for example.

Answer (score 2):

In previous versions Django allowed all hosts if DEBUG was set to True (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts ). I do now:

```
if DEBUG is True:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['domain.tld', 'www.domain.tld']
```